# Cannot set English as main language

Tags: babel, yathesis

I'm using a yathesis class to write my PhD thesis. 
I should use two languages like French and English. The main language should be English.
I tried `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}` to make a body of my document in English, but it doesn't work. Is anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 8.1.2 of the manual:

> **8.1.2 Langues (principale, secondaire, supplémentaires)**
>   Par défaut, un mémoire créé avec la classe `yathesis` est composé :
>   — en français comme langue principale ;
>   — en anglais comme langue secondaire.
>
> `mainlanguage=french|english` (pas de valeur par défaut, initialement french)
>   Pour que la langue principale — et activée par défaut — soit l’anglais, il suffit de le stipuler au moyen de l’option `mainlanguage=english`. Le français devient alors automatiquement la langue secondaire.

Briefly, in English: if you want English as the main language, add the class option `mainlanguage=english`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  mainlanguage=english,
  fncychap=none,
]{yathesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Punctuation}

Colons are not detached: see? The same for question mark; even
the semicolon is good.

\end{document}
```

[image]